# How can I force H2 exception messages to be in English?

Tags: h2

My customers run my desktop product that uses H2 as an embedded database. They are in many different locales. In the crash reports that I receive from customers, the H2 exceptions report in different languages. I'd like these messages always to be in English. How can I do this?

For example, I received this today in a crash report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.barbarysoftware.c.b.g: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL []; Division durch 0: "0"
Division by zero: "0"; SQL statement:
```

This is partly in German. I want it to be entirely in English.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to start the your application using the JVM switch: `-Duser.language=en`

Comment: That would change the locale for everything. I only want the h2 exception messages in english, as they are logged, and sent in crash reports, and not for end users.

Comment: Looking at the source code of H2 using `-Duser.language` (or `-Duser.locale`) seems your only option. It uses a "hardwired" call `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()` to determine the language for error messages. I think the only other way would be to remove the localized messages from the h2 jar file.

Comment: That function would be very useful. Translated exception messages don't make much sense, because average users wont technically understand what they mean and wont recompile the code to fix it ;).

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry there is currently no way to do it. The error message are localized. The reason why the message is listed in English as well is because sometimes English is clearer.

If you don't like this behavior, what about adding a database setting to disable it (just use the English message)? Patches are welcome!

Comment: It seems that the latest version available (1.4.197 Mar 18, 2018) still lacks language configuration setting...